# Ajuda sobre CRUD/Filtrar Arrays salvos no Localstorage

Tags: javascript, array, node.js, front-end, localstorage

Bom dia pessoal,

Sou um estudante de Front End (Ainda estou no inicio de POO em Js e ainda não dominei algumas funções avançadas da linguagem) com muita vontade de aprender e pesquisar, sinta-se a vontade para dizer que não pesquisei o suficiente(se for o caso).
Vou dar um breve contexto de como está minha ideia:

Esta é o meu primeiro projeto e irei me basear no CRUD abaixo, pretendo criar um Sistema de Gerenciamento de um Restaurante, no qual irei salvar os Objetos Cliente dentro do Array 'db_client', salvando ele no localstorage.

```
//Retornar o Array salvo no localstorage
const getLocalStorage = () => JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('db_client')) ?? []

//Salvar o Array no localstorage
const setLocalStorage = (dbClient) => localStorage.setItem("db_client", JSON.stringify(dbClient))

// CRUD - create read update delete

//Delete
const deleteClient = (index) => {
    const dbClient = readClient()
    dbClient.splice(index, 1)
    setLocalStorage(dbClient)
}

//Update
const updateClient = (index, client) => {
    const dbClient = readClient()
    dbClient[index] = client
    setLocalStorage(dbClient)
}

//Read
const readClient = () => getLocalStorage()


//Create
const createClient = (client) => {
    const dbClient = getLocalStorage()
    dbClient.push (client)
    setLocalStorage(dbClient)
}
```

Minha ideia/dúvida:
Cada Cliente irá ter uma posição no Array, correto? 0, 1, 2... etc.
Eu quero fazer um Front, onde a cada Cliente criado, ele se associe a um "Card" escrito Mesa 0,1,2,3... etc
E a numeração da Mesa, esteja associada a posição do Array.
Porém no meu Código, eu estou manipulando o Array através da variável "index" que estou digitando manualmente.
Ex.: updateCliente(1, cliente)

Que abstração posso fazer para tornar essa ação de digitar o "index" manualmente, em algo automatizado?
Automatizado no exemplo de: Na ação do usuário ao clicar em "Inserir/Salvar Mesa", o número da Mesa ser o mesmo da posição do Cliente no Array 'db_client'?

Por favor, alguém me dê alguma luz sobre essa abstração que precisa ser feita sobre o Index, porque se eu desejo automatizar tudo,
esse index vai interferir tanto nessa questão da Mesa, quanto no update/delete do CRUD.
Me digam se é possível fazer isso. Me indiquem links, materiais sobre, fico grato desde já.

Atenciosamente,
Igor

Answer (score -1):

Olá, Igor, tudo bem?

O LocalStorage é basicamente um armazenamento simples de pares chave/valor, no qual ambos são strings, não sendo ideal para armazenar dados estruturados como os seus.

Acredito que o IndexedDB seja uma alternativa melhor para o que está desenvolvendo, por permitir o armazenamento eficiente de grande quantidade de dados estruturados, além da consulta dos mesmos, o que resolve o problema em sua pergunta.

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Obrigado Claudio!

Comment: Vou dar uma pesquisada sobre. Entendo a simplicidade do Local Storage, mas queria saber manipular esses dados "na raça"/"no cru", e depois salvar no LocalStorage como um "backup" simples. Mas obrigado pela dica.